# how to make play/pause button

Tags: javascript, audio

I would like the pause button to resume the song from where it was paused instead of restarting the song.

with vanilla javascript only please,
Thank you !

```js
var songs = [
  "song1.mp3",
  "song2.mp3",
  "song3.mp3",
];

var song = new Audio();
var currentSong = 0;

var playButton = document.querySelector(".play");
var pauseButton = document.querySelector(".pause");

function playSong() {
  song.src = songs[currentSong];
  pauseButton.style.display = "block";
  playButton.style.display = "none";
  songTitle.textContent = sT[currentSong];
  Artist.textContent = artistNames[currentSong];
  songCover.src = songCovers[currentSong];
  song.play();
}

playButton.addEventListener("click", function playSong() {
  song.src = songs[currentSong];
  pauseButton.style.display = "block";
  playButton.style.display = "none";
  songTitle.textContent = sT[currentSong];
  Artist.textContent = artistNames[currentSong];
  songCover.src = songCovers[currentSong];
  song.play();
});

pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function pauseSong() {
  song.pause();
  pauseButton.style.display = "none";
  playButton.style.display = "block";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The song resets because every time you click on the `play` button, the `src` of the song is being assigned again. And therefor the song will start over from the start.

So you'll need to change the part of your code where the song is selected. Do that outside of the `play` function so that clicking play will only play, and clicking pause will only pause.

```
function chooseSong() {
  song.src = songs[currentSong];
  songTitle.textContent = sT[currentSong];
  Artist.textContent = artistNames[currentSong];
  songCover.src = songCovers[currentSong];
}

function playSong() {
  pauseButton.style.display = "block";
  playButton.style.display = "none";
  song.play();
}

function pauseSong() {
  pauseButton.style.display = "none";
  playButton.style.display = "block";
  song.pause();
}

playButton.addEventListener('click', playSong);
pauseButton.addEventListener('click', pauseSong);

chooseSong();
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? I kinda freestyled it here, because I thought it would work. But if so, let me know so that I can debug your code.

Comment: nevermind I messed up the code, it is working now thank you very much